# Upgrading Joomla! 1.7.2 Stable to 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need to upgrade Joomla! 1.7.2 Stable to 2.5 (Its a live site)

Some of my doubts are

```
 Does the design changes back to the original default one.If so how can i recover it back?

 Are there any good blog to refer its step by step process?

 Are there any extension manager to do it with less error and quickly?

 Jomsocial 2.4 is installed in it, does upgrading Joomla 2.5 will affect the files in 
 Jomsocial,because I have done some updations in these files(in components/com_community 
 and components/com_users)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below link to get more information

1. http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_from_an_existing_version
2. http://www.ijoomla.com/blog/joomla-2-5-what-to-expect-how-to-upgrade-from-joomla-1-5-or-1-7/
3. http://brian.teeman.net/joomla-1.7/upgrading-to-joomla-2.5-some-warnings.html